# GNOSIS SAFE WEB SITE: Format error when passing a param value

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

Hellow, I'm trying to pass the arguments of a param but I get a format error, the param is this:
[image]

When I pass this param in the code I just send this array:
`[{"target":"0x891875d06c044c160F01Ca620BED8ecB55d529E5","action":0,"selectors":["0x834077fc"]}`

But now I'm not the owner and I'm trying to use the multiSigWallet (current owner) but in my tries I get different types of error as follow:

[image]

or

[image]

and the last one

[image]

As you can see, it works like a JSON but when I follow the format I get the n.map error, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try without quotes

Comment: With [[0x891875d06c044c160F01Ca620BED8ecB55d529E5,0,[]]] I get the last format error but at position 3 (line 1 column 4)

Comment: Guess the quotes are needed for some values and not needed for other values. Can you try different combinations?

Comment: I tried with a lot of combinations, probably is Gnosis that doesn't work with complex structs?

Comment: I haven't used safe this much. Did you reach out on their discord? That would definitely help.

Comment: Yep, I post my question there and no one knew how to answer me, and the support chat told me this is a complex question for them, and that I need to post it here